# Differentiate users by their email address

Tags: java, android

I have two questions:

1. How can I differentiate @123.com users and @abc.com users? These emails are school and organization emails that are in outlook, so I don't think I can use the fireBase for authentication check. I did some research online and found a Youtube video on how to implement Outlook SDK. I might be able to use that.
2. Some features will be only available for @123.com users, but hidden from @abc.com users. How can I make that possible?

Comment: #1 `boolean is123user = email.endsWith("@123.com");` --- #2 `if (is123user)`

Comment: Authentication and authorization are pretty broad topics; there are nearly unlimited ways this could be implemented.